# CSS definition for to get rid of the of the browsers select field

Tags: css

[![I have styled a select2 dropdown, which you can see in attached screenshots. which works fine with desktop browsers, but with Chrome for ios it shows the browsers own select2-dropdown in foreground and the css-styled select2-dropdown behind it. When choosing a value with the browsers select field no value is taken but the browsers foreground select is hidden and one can use the css-style dropdown, which works and accepts the choosen value.
How can i get rid of the browsers select?
[image: Select2 in background]

[image: Select2 in foreround]

Comment: Can you show us your code? Without seeing your code is difficult to help you. The first thing that comes to my mind is `appearance: none;`, but you probably already are using it...

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the hint. `But appearance: none;` is already in use.
That is the 
`/* <select> styles */
select {
/* Reset */
appearance: none;
border: 1px solid #3b475e63;
outline: 0;
font: inherit;
height: 2.8em;
padding: 0 4em 0 1em;
color: #3B475E;
border-radius: 0.25em;
cursor: pointer;
}`